# Flex - fixed number of items on row with equal space between while keeping original ratio

Tags: css, flexbox, css-multicolumn-layout

Assuming this HTML

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">Some</div>
    <div class="box">Something</div>
    <div class="box">A</div>
    <div class="box">Something longer</div>
    <div class="box">B</div>
    <div class="box">Lemons</div>
</div>
```

I was presented with a rather stranger design, where there is:

- fixed number of "boxes" on each row - **3** to be specific
- same space between boxes on the line (let's say 15px)
- they are spread while keeping their **original ratio among themselves** (the imaginary "left space" on the row is distributed as their width but based on their oririnal size **ratio** - **not equaly**

If there would not be the ratio issue, CSS would be

```
.boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;  
}
.boxes .box {
    background: #006600;
    flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 15px);
    padding: 12px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Problem with this solution is that the boxes always take 1/3 becuse of the flex-basis, if I don't set the flex-basis, there are more boxes than 3 per row.

Basically I need something like

```
.boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
}
.boxes .box {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

But with a set number of items per row - is that even possilbe?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I am looking for a way how to do this without altering the HTML, if you are able to alter the HTML you can simply spread it with `flex-grow: 1` and put a breaking element after each N of items or wrap each N of items in a separate row (flex container).

Comment: use CSS grid for this

Comment: @TemaniAfif is that achievable using flexbox layout though? The backwards browser compatibility is slightly better there

Comment: @TemaniAfif also could provide a solution/hint on how to do this with CSS grid?

Comment: what do you mean by *ratio* ? technically, your elements don't have any ratio since they are a div elements (images have ratio)

Comment: @TemaniAfif images have ratio between their width and height, I am talking about ratio between the widths of each element on the row - since each element has a content of a different length, therefore a different "starting width" - see what happens if you just use flex-grow: 1 on 3 elements with a different-length-content, sidenote: **all elements** have a starting width:height ratio depending on their content or pre-set dimensions, that is however not the ratio I am talking about here.