Flexbox or CSS - n number of items per row without stretching the item. Using tailwind or CSS
Is there any way to force a certain number of items per row using flex box or any other way in CSS / tailwind, without stretching the item's width? and making them stick to left with same horizontal margin
For my case, lets assume 4 items per row:-


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>
<h1 class="mt-6">my failed attempt:-</h1>
<div class="flex flex-wrap bg-gray-300">
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-yellow-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-blue-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-orange-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-red-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-neutral-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-green-500 p-10"></div>
  <!-- ... more unknown number of elements with unknown width -->
</div>

<h1 class="mt-6">what i want:-</h1>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="m-2 bg-yellow-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-blue-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-orange-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-red-500 p-10"></div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="m-2 bg-teal-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-cyan-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-stone-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-pink-500 p-10"></div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="m-2 bg-green-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-black p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-slate-500 p-10"></div>
</div>




If you just want a responsive variant which automatically uses the available space and adds breaking the tiles if needed, you can set the properties display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; on the parent container.

Alternatively you can try display: grid.

Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186405/flex-fixed-number-of-items-on-row-with-equal-space-between-while-keeping-origi

Try grid, grid-cols-*, gap-*
Tailwind CSS documentation for reference


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>
<div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
  <div class="w-28 h-28 bg-yellow-500"></div>
  <div class="w-32 h-32 bg-blue-500"></div>
  <div class="w-36 h-36 bg-orange-500"></div>
  <div class="w-40 h-40 bg-red-500"></div>
  <div class="w-4 h-4 bg-neutral-500"></div>
  <div class="w-12 h-12 bg-green-500"></div>
  <!-- ... more unknown number of elements with unknown width -->
</div>




thanks! is there any way I can remove the inconsistent horizontal margin between them, and make them all stick to left, with common horizontal margin length? that will be exactly what i meant



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>
<h1 class="mt-6">my failed attempt:-</h1>
<div class="grid grid-cols-4 bg-gray-300">
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-yellow-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-blue-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-orange-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-red-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-neutral-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 grow basis-1/5 bg-green-500 p-10"></div>
  <!-- ... more unknown number of elements with unknown width -->
</div>

<h1 class="mt-6">what i want:-</h1>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="m-2 bg-yellow-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-blue-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-orange-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-red-500 p-10"></div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="m-2 bg-teal-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-cyan-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-stone-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-pink-500 p-10"></div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="m-2 bg-green-500 p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-black p-10"></div>
  <div class="m-2 bg-slate-500 p-10"></div>
</div>



Use this grid-cols-* with Tailwind CSS and replace * with "n" number of columns you want and add grid before this. If you want gap between these columns then you can use gap-*.

thanks! they are still stretching and becoming rectangles, i want them to keep their width
